# Sending a command to a running process using a named pipe

Tags: c, named-pipes

I have a program that runs as a service, which takes the standard input from the console, and prints the feedback to the screen. It can be thought as the following simple example, while the `printf()` function is actually some more complicated function.

```
//keyin.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[80];
    int i = 1;

    while(i++){ 
    printf("enter %d string: \n", i);
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("print %d string: %s \n\n", i, buf);
    sleep(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to use a named pipe as the input so that I can use another program to pass desired commands to the service by writing to the pipe, instead of typing in the console.

I created a named pipe by:

```
mknod MYFIFO p
```

and then I redirect the input by:

```
root@ubuntu: ./keyin < MYFIFO
```

and then I write the command into pipe by:

```
root@ubuntu: echo "test" > MYFIFO
```

I expect the service take the "test", print it out, and wait for the next input, however, after the first run, it keeps printing out "test" infinitely, and never responds to the pipe file again, even when I delete it.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `scanf()`. Note that for every time you get the same repeated buffer, `scanf()` would return a negative value.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char buf[80];
   int i = 1;
       while(i++){
       if(scanf("%s", buf) > 0){
           printf("print %d string: %s \n\n", i, buf);
       }
       sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that a named pipe is not like a normal pipe or the console and **will** behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your solution does works in this scanf/printf case, but the while() loop keeps running. My real program is much complicated than a simple scanf() and therefore I am unable to do this. I hope there is a solution that can make the program hang there until the next command is issued. And other than name pipe, do you have any other solution for this? Say I have only a binary executable, test.exe, which takes keyboard input and do some action accordingly. Now I want test.exe runs background as a service and use another program to pass command to test.exe, how can I do this?

Comment: Thank you, I think I know where the problem is. Named pipe needs to be connected to both a writer and a reading. In the echo "test">MYPIPE case, the pipe file was closed after the echo, therefore the reader got an EOF, and then entered the infinite loop. Instead using "keyin<MYFIFO", I use "tail -f MYFIFO|keyin", the tail command will ignore the EOF so now it works fine.